# Blazor .net 8 rc1 RenderModeWebAssembly stopped working

Tags: blazor, .net-8.0

Running Blazor on .Net 8 RC1 with a mix of Server-Side- static and interactive rendered and a couple of web assembly components.
Up until several hours ago this worked, and everything was running smoothy, but than it stopped loading the Client program.cs and thus none of the client-side WASM components render even with RenderModeWebAssembly attribute applied.

I tripple checked that I am configured to load the WebAssemblyComponents from the client project.
Here is the Server Program.cs..

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

    builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
          .AddServerComponents()
          .AddWebAssemblyComponents();
    
    
    builder.Logging.AddConfiguration(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    
    builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger), provider => provider.GetService<ILogger<Program>>());
    builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
     
    builder.Services.AddMudServices();
    builder.Services.AddMudServicesConfiguration();
    builder.Services.AddServicesConfiguration();
     
    var app = builder.Build();
    
     
    
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    
    app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
        .AddWebAssemblyRenderMode().AddServerRenderMode();
     
    app.Run();
```

And here is the Program.cs from the client project (WASM)...

```
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger), provider => provider.GetService<ILogger<Program>>());
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

builder.Services.AddWASMServicesConfiguration();

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

This is my server-side Home page consisting of two components, the top is ServerSide interactive rendered while the bottom is suppose to be [RenderModeWebAssembly]

```
@page "/"
@using NextWare.UI.PageBuilder.Components

 
<PageTitle>Page Editor</PageTitle>

<PageEditorCanvas/> 
<NextWare.UI.PageBuilder.Client.HtmlPageEditor/>
```

Previously (when was working from a clean browser storage), I was seeing the WASM files downloading and it would render the HtmlPageEditor twice, the first was as a PreRendered html from the server then once the WASM was downloaded it rendered the component and ran as a WebAssembly.
Previously, I could set break-points on the Program.cs for both the server and client side projects and I would reliably hit them both when their time came to execute.

This suddenly stopped, and I don't understand as to why.

Now when I run from a clean browser storage, I still see the WASM files being downloaded, however it only renders the client HtmlPageEditor component once (prerendered from server), unlike previous where it ran twice.
Further I no longer hit the break points in the client program.cs.

It seemingly knows to pull down the WASM but it never attempts to reload to run component as a WebAssembly rendered component. Why??

I've tried deleting the obj/bin/.vs folders in server and client projects and clean, full rebuild and recompiling to no avail.

I tried applying the attribute directly on the instance of the PageEditor WASM component.

I am able to create a new Blazor Server/WASM interactive sample projects and they work fine.
I ran a code compare of the program startups between the sample and my projects and they look like they are setup correctly.

There are no web debugger exceptions, as well, there are no server side exceptions. It simply stopped working.

Here is an high-level view of what I am creating. It is a Blazor based page builder that uses JS Interop to integrate with a JS Html editor, and provides away to create Blazor components from discrete components. This is part of our larger App Builder initiative.

[image]

I have reduced this to a simple model yet still this no longer works.

Are there any additional logs I can interrogate that can help me understand what is at play.

Comment: The obvious things to try are Ctrl+F5 in the browser, restarting VS (and maybe even your PC).

Comment: thanks all those were tried, including restarting of computer.

Comment: Start eliminating possible causes: use a different browser, does a new and clean standard template app still work?  etc.

Comment: I've gone through Firefox, Chrome and Edge, all run same way. Yes a new project does work.  I've compared the working client and server projects, and aside from the extra libs and subtle startup logic on broken projects, there isn't much that's different.

Comment: And what does your sourcecontrol have to say?  Compare with the last known-good version.

Comment: My bad, this is kind of working.   The issue was related to the debugger not attaching to the client side rendered instance of the component.  I've been struggling with Launching  the Browser (Chrome, Edge, FF..), so I set the  "launchBrowser": false.  What was happening is that it would crash upon start-up, but does not if I manually run the app.  Previously I could launch and debug the Client-only logic, now this is broken.  That said, I am able to use the Browser debugger, so I will continue this way until RC 2 hopefully resolves my env. issues.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that VS debugger does not attach to the Browser debugger because I had to manually invoke the browser as otherwise at start-up on debug, it crashes.
When I launch the browser manually, this gave the illusion that it wasn't running the WASM instance (second pass), but that was not the case.

It actually is running, however VS does not proxy-debug to the client side JS debugger, so it appeared to not be working, but upon further investigation, it actually is running the WASM instance.

This is what I had changed that caused all the confusion...

```
"https": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": false,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  },
  "dotnetRunMessages": true,
  "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7120;http://localhost:5113"
},
```

I had to set  `"launchBrowser": false,` because I was crashing when launching into Debug of the app.

I am not sure why I can't launch the browser automatically (tried FF, Chrome and Edge), but at least I am able to continue and hoping that this will be resolved in RC2.